# Doit-on considérer "voici" comme une phrase ou une interjection ?

Tags: grammaire, sens

On trouve à la dernière page de *Sodome et Gomorrhe* de Marcel Proust :

« Je sais la peine que je vais te faire. D’abord au
lieu de rester ici comme tu le voulais, je vais partir en même
temps que toi. Mais cela n’est encore rien. Je me porte mal
ici, j’aime mieux rentrer. Mais écoute-moi, n’aie pas trop de
chagrin. **Voici**. Je me suis trompé, je t’ai trompée de bonne
foi hier, j’ai réfléchi toute la nuit. Il faut absolument, et décidons-le tout de suite, parce que je me rends bien compte
maintenant, parce que je ne changerai plus, et que je ne
pourrais pas vivre sans cela, il faut absolument que j’épouse
Albertine. »

Doit-on considérer **voici**, dans ce cas, comme une phrase ou une interjection ?

Answer (score 2):

« Voici » dans le texte cité **est une phrase** si on regarde des définitions de la phrase :

Grevisse (*Le bon usage*, 10<sup>e</sup> édition, 172.2) dit que « la phrase simple contient une seule proposition », et par ailleurs (228) il définit la *proposition elliptique* comme une « proposition dont le verbe n'est pas exprimé ; en raccourcissant l'expression, elle traduit la pensée avec une spontanéité, une vivacité ou une énergie particulière. »

Certains linguistiques ont défini le concept de mot-phrase :

> Le mot-phrase est un mot qui peut constituer à lui seul un énoncé remplissant du point de vue sémantique le rôle d’une phrase simple, sans être un verbe pour autant.
> Dans des grammaires de certaines langues, comme le français ou le hongrois, la notion de mot-phrase comprend, parmi les parties du discours pris en compte par les grammaires traditionnelles, la classe de l’interjection et partiellement celle de l’adverbe.<sup>1</sup>

Pour moi sans nul doute « Voici » dans le texte cité est une phrase.

Est-ce une interjection dans ce même texte en question ? À mon avis **ce n'est pas une interjection**. Pour dire ceci je me réfère à Grevisse :

> L'interjection est une sorte de cri qu'on jette dans le discours pour exprimer un mouvement de l'âme, un état de pensée, un ordre, un avertissement, un appel : « Ah ! que de bruit ! Allons, vous dis-je. – Çà, votre main ». (Molière, *Le bourgeois gentilhomme*, V. 5).
> Les interjections sont généralement brèves et se réduisent souvent à une seule syllabe. Ordinairement elles sont, dans l'écriture, suivies du point d'exclamation. (*Le bon usage*, 10<sup>e</sup> édition)

Voir aussi la [définition de l'interjection](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection) dans Wikipedia :

> L'interjection peut également consister en un syntagme ou en une phrase. Certains grammairiens la définissent parfois comme un mot-phrase, puisqu'à elle seule, elle équivaut à toute une phrase, de type exclamatif ou interrogatif.

À mon avis dans le texte de Proust cité dans la question « voici » est une simple phrase elliptique exprimant « voici ce que je pense » et qui sert à introduire l’explication qui va suivre.

**« Voici » peut-il être une interjection ?**
Certainement à mon avis, par exemple dans le passage suivant :

> – Tu veux bien me rendre mon stylo ?
> – Voici ! (dit d'un ton agacé)

Dans mon exemple « voici » est une phrase **et** une interjection.
D'ailleurs si on se réfère aux définitions ci-dessus toute interjection est une phrase.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> [Article Mot-phrase](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot-phrase) de Wikipedia.</sup>